# How to check if a DB array matches any values of a given array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm a little bit stuck.

I have an SQL column that contains weather codes (like Rain, Snow, etc.)
It is comma separated so the column would have a value of something like

> rain,snow,haze

Now, I want to select the rows that contain values from an array.

I have an SQL code that is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE currentWeather IN ('rain', 'snow', 'cloudy') ORDER BY name ASC
```

The problem is that this obviously works when currentWeather column only contains one item.
Is there a way to do it so that if the column value *contains* any of the items from the given array, it selects it?

Also, would it select it twice if two items match?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unnest in a subselect.

`Select distinct A.myArray from (select unnest(column) as myArray from table) A where A.myArray in (your words to filter for)`

Notice that using arrays in sql isn't very ideal and does not follows normalization rules. Your tables should ideally not contain arrays but rather just several rows each one containing the specific value you Want. It prevents issues such as this one.

To avoid the selection of repeated values, use the Distinct keyword right after you write select.

Rsference:

https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql_unnest-function.php

Comment: Does this work for MariaDB? After editing the relevant columns etc I get the error:

database.unnest does not exist

Comment: Nope, MariaDB is essentially a fork of MySQL, theres no equivalent to unnest in MySQL. Remember to include a tag that references the DMBS you're using when you have SQL questions, or at least mention it in the post. May I ask what are you trying to do with this? Not from an SQL perspective but from code? There may very well be a solution to your problem at the program level.

Comment: Ah, that's annoying then. I might have to redesign how I attempt this problem then.

I realised I had missed out the DB so I have added that in but I don't think there's an easy way round it unfortunately :(

Comment: But once again, what are you trying to do in your program? I have a feeling that whatever you're trying to do can be accomplished at the program level. For example, you could retrieve the whole array from SQL, store it in a variable in your program, then implement logic to select only the words you want from the array.

Regardless, I have answered the question you asked, please consider selecting my answer.

Comment: So, I'm trying to print out only the locations where there is one or more of the "allowed" values, so to speak.
I thought there might be an "explode" function within SQL that would allow me to work with comma separated values but it seems like there isn't so I think you're right and it would be easier to do it at the program level.

Comment: Yes to my knowledge MySql (and thus, MariaDB) doesn't have an equivalent of unnest. However then there's, in my opinion, a fundamental design flaw in your database. Why did you store multiple values for a location, instead of creating multiple rows for the location each one listing one of its weather values?
Like, lets say you have Utah in the location column, rather than having just 1 row that says "Snowy, windy, sunny", you could have 3 rows saying "Utah | Snowy", "Utah | Windy |", "Utah | Sunny". This would completely spare you your current troubles.

Comment: If you want, you can keep the current structure and in your program just split the string into a list, then iterate through the list and remove the elements that don't match your criteria, then return the array..

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(currentWeather, "rain,snow,cloudy")
```

Picks apart the string at commas (only) to see if `currentWeather` is any one of those 3 'words'.

See also `FIELD(...)`

Comment: Would this work if currentWeather is also a comma separated value, for example ('snow', haze')?

Comment: No, this takes a string as a parameter and internally separates each word by the comma.
Additionally, I don't believe this would help your case because this only finds the first occurrence and it stops looking, also, this only returns the position of the string, it does not return the string itself. I don't have MySql at home to test if it can take a column as a parameter. You may try passing your currentWeather as the 2nd parameter and see what happens, but like I said, I don't think this will solve your problem.